# Star Schema: Triple Relations between Fact and Dimension

Tags: database, database-design, schema, data-warehouse, erd

I'm modelling a Star Schema from an ERD. The Database is a rental firm. My fact table now contains a single Rental Booking. Customers are able to book cars, collect cars and return cars. The date of when this happens should be recorded.

So, my Star Schema now has a Time Dimension with Day/Month/Year and three relations to the fact table. I'm wondering if that's the right way to do or if there are other options to consider, because I have never seen a Star Scheme where a dimension has more than one Relation.

This is it:

```
 Booking(Fact)
 bookingId
 bookingDate(FK)
 collectionDate(FK)
 returnDate(FK)

 Time(Dim)
 timeId
 day
 month
 year
```

Comment: Your schema is correct. A fact table can have more than one relation with a dimension table. This is sometime called “shared hierarchy”.

Comment: Oh ok good to know! If you post an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @coolMan how would you join the time dimension to the booking table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a Fact join to the same dimension multiple times. I've seen this used with Time dimensions especially. 
I'm not sure what key you are using to join the Fact to the Time dim, but you may end up with a query like this, when selecting the data:

```
select bFact.bookingID,t1.day "Booking Date",t2.day "Collection Date",t3.day "Return Date"
from Booking bFact
join Time t1 on t1.date = bFact.bookingDate
join Time t2 on t2.date = bFact.collectionDate
join Time t3 on t3.date = bFact.returnDate
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a diagram to try and help you understand better.

[image]

If your bookingdate, collectiondate, returndate are all part of the time dimension then you dont need them in the fact table. They need to be in the dimension table.

I have created a diagram that would correctly demonstrate what i think you mean.
As an example, if return can have different measures then it needs to be a separate dimension. Each dimension will always need a primary key and these will always correspond to a foreign key in the fact table.

Any questions let me know

Comment: If you have booking date, collection date and return date, the id of all three should be in the fact: that's how you distinguish between all three. They all would link to time id from the time (date) dimension.

Comment: @Rich i disagree. It doesn't make sense having 3 different date related dimensions, there should only be 1 date related dimension which then all the others can link to through the fact time. So you would have time(which would include date), collection(would contain collection data and can link to the time dimension to retrieve date info) and the same for return. Holding date information in multiple dimensions is just going to cause you data integrity issues.

Comment: @Rich e.g if you reported on everything booked,returned or collected from the time dimension, in your scenario you would be missing all the data from collected or returned dimensions purely because they hold the date information separately.

Comment: I agree, you should only have one date dimension. It describes the dates. In your fact table you would have a BookingDateID (which links to your one date dimension) and in the same fact table you would have a CollectionDateID (which links to your one date dimension) and so on. This situation has a need for a single fact table to refer to (not store) multiple dates. Its the common concept of a 'role playing dimension' in the Kimball literature. Same as if you had a 'order entry employee' and a 'order dispatch employee' in the same fact, both pointing to one dimension.

Comment: @Rich There is already only 1 fact table. There should never be more than one. What happens if you wanted to store different data in both collection and return fields? I would think they would need to be different dimensions at that stage

Comment: What do you mean by ‘there should never be more than one?’ One fact table represents one collection of measurements taken for a business process. If you wanted to have a different date for collection date and return date they just have different date ids which refer to the single date dimension.

Comment: @Rich You should only ever have one fact table per diagram. I mean what happens when you want to hold more information on a return? e.g return number, return item etc

Comment: That’s a separate issue of ‘should this be modelled as separate fact tables for the different processes?’ This question is more about ‘what if a fact needs to record more than one date’ which is a very common situation. See ‘role playing dimensions’ and also ‘accumulating snapshot facts’ for more info.

Comment: I see. I was coming at it from different processes angle